# Web audio - Analyser frequency data not 0 during silence

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I create sounds using oscillator nodes and want to draw a frequency visualization on a canvas. When the oscillator is playing, the visualization looks like this (standard oscillator settings, see code below).
http://i58.tinypic.com/wtvwgz.png

After the oscillator stopped playing (complete silence!), this is what I get. The exact result changes from run to run, sometimes the values even keep slightly changing after the stop.
http://i62.tinypic.com/2duji81.png

I don't understand why the frequency data is not zero for all bins, when the sound is not playing.

Tested on Firefox 30.0 and Iron 34.0.1850.0 (Chrome)

Here's my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext
                    || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext)();

                var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
                analyser.fftSize = 512;
                analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
                var frequencyBins = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

                var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
                osc.connect(analyser);
                osc.start(audioContext.currentTime + 2);
                osc.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 4);

                var WIDTH = 512;
                var HEIGHT = 100;
                var value, h, w;

                function draw() {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                    for (var i = 0; i < frequencyBins.length; i++) {
                        value = frequencyBins[i];
                        h = HEIGHT * (value / 255);
                        w = WIDTH / frequencyBins.length;
                        ctx.fillRect(i * w, HEIGHT - 1, w, -h);
                    }
                };

                function animate() {
                    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyBins);
                    draw();
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="100"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting observation. visualizing the input data by replacing `getByteFrequencyData` with `getByteTimeDomainData` suggests that actually the input buffer for the frequency analysis is not set to zero after the osc stops. On the other hand, the frequency graph looks like the time domain data was cut off in the middle. On my MacBook, when I set the osc time to around 15s, I see a constantly decaying frequency graph at the end. Have you verified the behavior with other input sources?

Comment: Interesting indeed. I was wondering if it was the noise floor being picked up. I put your code in jsfiddle and added changed the minDecible value so we can see the noise floor. It doesn't seem to be like it's noise. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/7759c/2/

Comment: It seems when the Oscillator has stopped emitting new audio data, the last frame of data is kept and used to return the time and frequency domain data by the Analyser Node. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/7759c/3/

Comment: @PeterSorowka So far I've only used an oscillator as input. I'll try to play a sound file later.

Comment: @notthetup Sometimes the frequency data keeps changing after the stop. Had a few tests were the data slowly shifted towards higher frequencies. Might still be based on the last frame though, maybe the smoothingTimeConstant plays a role here?

Comment: @Prometheus I also thought that but verified that the behavior is the same when setting `smoothingTimeConstant` to `0`. Btw a noise floor usually does not show such a curve in the spectrum, pure white noise has an almost constant frequency envelope. It is a pitty that the frequency analysis functions are so obscure and biased in special situations. I could not even discover if and which windowing functions are in use...

Comment: I believe the WebAudio spec doesn't define the window to be used. But it seems like all browsers are using Blackman. http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2014AprJun/0001.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

Instead of connecting the oscillator directly to the analyser, I pass the frequencies through a high-pass filter first. It seems that the value for the cutoff frequency can be set arbitrarily low, as long as it is not 0. Even with a cutoff of 0.00000001 the visualisation will be blank during silence.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2ZL9/3/

```
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 512;
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
var frequencyBins = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

var filter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = "highpass";
filter.frequency.value = 0.0001;
filter.connect(analyser);

var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.connect(filter);
osc.start(audioContext.currentTime + 2);
osc.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 4);
```

Comment: My analyser's result during silence was a little different - it was a constant magnitude across all frequencies. Nevertheless, this method solved it for me (thanks), though I still don't understand how applying a high-pass filter helped

Comment: While adding a highpass filter improved the quality of my analyser, it cannot of itself fix freezing. Freezing is caused by analyser insensitivity. Lowering the minimum dB threshold resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a noise floor.  It happens with audio buffers too.  It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was analyserNode.smoothingTimeConstant, it has very high value by default. Try to
analyserNode.smoothingTimeConstant = 0; //or 0.2
It will fix it

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing the same issue I tried:

- Various biquad filters
- Various window functions

While I got the best results with a 2K-highpass/blackman combo, the freeze still persisted.

In the end I also had to adjust the min/max dB settings of the analyser. I had originally set min/max dB to -100/0.

- min dB of -101 yielded slow melting during silence.
- min dB of -150 yielded fast melting.

Intuitively it makes sense that increasing the response range of the analyser would resolve this issue. I assume it can be traced to quantization in the FFT algo.

Notes:

The highpass filter doubles overall processing overhead :(

While I also found that changing the smoothingTimeConstant to values approaching 1.0 resolved the freezing, it also induced lag in the responsiveness of the analyser (too smooth).